# Move a QT form that has attribute Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wanted to get rid of the default buttons on top of a form along with the border of the form. So I used the following

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

This meets my criteria however now the problem is I cannot move the form on the screen any suggestions on how I may resolve this issue ?

Comment: You can implement dragging capabilities of your form, when user can move it by mouse press-drag-release.

Comment: [This example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be setting more flags than just CustomizeWindowHint.

If the window is just a widget: -

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

If it's a main Window: -

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Else, if it's a dialog: -

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

Then, as @vahancho commented, you'll need to handle the dragging of the window yourself as, by default, windows don't move when dragged, unless done so by the title bar.